# Password can be circumvented by plugging in external screen

Tags: password, security

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04. and I have a serious security issue. When my laptop is closed it goes to standby. When I then open it again it asks (as it should) for my password. But if my laptop is closed and I plug in an external monitor via an HDMI port and open it, it automatically logs in without asking me for the password.

Any idea as to why this is the case and what I can do about it?

My system:

Model : Dell Inc. Inspiron 5406 2n1
OS:   Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Gnome Version: 42.2

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Check your settings in security and privacy in Ubuntu settings.  There is a check box to ask for password after suspend.

Comment: It's checked! :)

Comment: Is the laptop plugged in?  What are your power settings when plugged in?  Are you sure the laptop is going into suspend or just low power?

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a 22.04 Live USB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. If you can, then file a bug report listing step-by-step how to reproduce the problem using that specific environment. Be super detailed in your bug report. If you cannot reproduce the issue in a LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment, then it's likely some setting or customization. A developer usually needs to be able to reliably reproduce an issue in their environment in order to troubleshoot, diagnose, and fix it.